# How to update millions of records in MySQL using LIMIT in subquery?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem updating ~3.7 million records in the MySQL database. I have two tables - `a_names` and `a_records` and I need to update `records` with **new names** from `names` table. As for now, the best I can think about is using `LEFT JOIN`, but the updates take forever and usually results in a timeout.
There are 15.4k records in `a_names` table.

```
UPDATE a_records AS a
LEFT JOIN a_names AS b
ON a.name = b.old_name
SET a.name = b.new_name;
```

I have tried suggested solutions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51917838/12193952), however using `LIMIT` in my query results in an error:

```
UPDATE a_records AS a
LEFT JOIN a_names AS b
ON a.name = b.old_name
SET a.name = b.new_name
WHERE a.id IN (
    SELECT a.id
    FROM a_records as a
    LEFT JOIN a_names as b
    ON a.name = b.old_name
    WHERE a.name <> b.new_name
    LIMIT 10
)
```

```
Query 1 ERROR: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

I am using `8.0.29-0ubuntu0.22.04.2` version of MySQL, which is AFAIK the latest release.

I also cannot use `JOIN` instead of updating the records as suggested in the given answer. It's not possible due to the technical limitations of the end users' software.

I am also thinking about writing a small script that is gonna download data from SQL, join and update data locally and upload them chunk-by-chunk in some temp table. After the whole update is done, I will replace the origin with the temp table. But I would like to stick to the SQL to learn something new.

Could you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Please also provide the SQL statement that leads to this error.  (WARNING: answers exist on stackoverflow for this problem!, see: [MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu)

Comment: @Luuk well, SELECT is not the same as UPDATE, but it helped me to solve the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adjusting the query based on the given suggestions, this one is working OK so far

```
UPDATE a_records AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a.id, b.new_name
    FROM a_records AS a
    LEFT JOIN a_names AS b
    ON a.name = b.old_name
    WHERE a.name <> b.new_name
    LIMIT 10000
) AS a2
ON a.id = a2.id
SET a.name = a2.new_name
WHERE a2.id IS NOT NULL
```

I will try to tweak the query a bit and post updated.